# How can I remove the blank gap between the footer and the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I am currently stuck on a problem. There is a gap between the footer and the bottom of the page. 
Some information and things I tried and didn't work out:

- body and html has 0 margin and 0 padding
- Change the size of the body
- trying to change the position of the footer
- probably some other things too, but forgot already about it

Heres the code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <section>
      <div class="section1">
          ...
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
      ...
    </footer>
  </body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, header, nav, section, footer{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-color: #ededed;
}
body{
  position: relative;
}
section{
  margin-top: 7.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 880px;
}
footer{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #474747;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
  section{
    height: 1000px;
  }
}
```

When the page looses at height the footer begins to float over the other things.
Here you have some screenshots:

- http://prntscr.com/sof9op (normal)
- http://prntscr.com/sof9yl (minimized the browser tab height a bit)
- http://prntscr.com/sofa3b (minimized the browser tab height a lot)
- http://prntscr.com/sofa76 (View from an Ipad Pro)
- http://prntscr.com/sofaa2 (View from an Iphone X)

This is my first question, so I actually don't know if anybody actually replies on this. But I would really appreciate it if somebody does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried deleting the codes I removed between these lines ? This will probably solve your problem.

```
  html, body, header, nav, section, footer {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-color: #ededed;
  }
```

Example :

```css
/* html, body, header, nav, section, footer{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-color: #ededed;
} */

* { /* If you set the width height value for all elements, there will be problems. You can use this to remove all margin and padding values on the page.  */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

section {
  margin-top: 7.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 880px;
}

footer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #474747;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  section {
    height: 1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="section1">
      Sections
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    Footer Area
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. As I can see in the code snippet seems to work. I still have the problem that there is a blank gap between the footer and the bottom of the page... But thanks to you I know the problem is somewhere else!

Comment: I'm glad I was of help. Note the width and height values that you give to the main elements. If you don't need it much, try not to value elements like `body` .Sometimes they can have unexpected results.

Comment: Ok i literally figgured out how to solve the whole problem:  just add: `body{overflow: hidden;}` to it in the `@media screen and (max-width:1024px){}` part - now i just have to change the height for higher resolutions than desktop!

Answer (score 0):

You could try use `min-height: calc (100vh - height of the header in px - height of the footer in px)` and you put that inside the section. i think will solve.

Comment: I put `min-height: calc(100vh - 270px);` into section, but it did not fix the big gap between the footer and the bottom of the page. there are actually now two scrolling bars (wtf?) when i just minimize the height of the browser tab a little bit

Comment: Ok the solution to the two scroll bars thing is just add: `body{overflow: hidden;}` to it in the `@media screen and (max-width:1024px){}` part

Comment: just to know, 270px is the sum of the heights?, but anyway had the same prob one time and this helped me. but before say i dont know the answer, 270px is the sum?